# Duplicate answers

Tags: discussion, community, reputation

For example; a question that has a perfectly good answer that has been accepted, has lots of upvotes and generally covers everything.

For some insane reason, people think that by posting an answer and simply ***repeating*** what others have said is acceptable. But of course, for another insane reason people deem these answers good enough to be **upvoted**. Orly? Ya rly.

Of course posting a different answer to explore a different solution, why not, but when the idea is merely to say exactly what everyone else has, it just seems like reputation whoring to me. This annoys me so much, I often delete my own answers to questions because someone else answers the same damn thing.

And this is even worse when the question is a duplicate, and people post the same freaking answers as on the original question.

In a site that tends to aim for (and I quoth) *pearls, not sand*, I believe that duplicate answers should also be flagged, and burned.

I strive to comment on answers that I think need to be clarified or could benefit from extra info, not **copy** the answer and amend it.

So, I guess my questio*rant*n is whether we could do anything about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vote them down and leave a comment why.  A common response is that the owner of the answer will delete it himself (assuming he doesn't think that his answer adds something more of value).  Either way it'll filter the dupes to the bottom of the list (assuming you're going by default sorting).

Comment: Yeah, that was a bit of a rant, I'll do that in the future.